# Webscraping Issue w/ BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I am new to Python web scraping, and I am scraping productreview.com for review. The following code pulls all the data I need for a single review:

```
#Scrape TrustPilot for User Reviews (Rating, Comments)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
import requests
import datetime as dt
final_list=[]
url = 'https://www.productreview.com.au/listings/world-nomads'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
for div in soup.find('div', class_ = 'loadingOverlay_24D'):
    try:
        name = soup.find('h4', class_ = 'my-0_27D align-items-baseline_kxl flex-row_3gP d-inline-flex_1j8 text-muted_2v5')
        name = name.find('span').text
        location = soup.find('h4').find('small').text
        policy = soup.find('div', class_ ='px-4_1Cw pt-4_9Zz pb-2_1Ex card-body_2iI').find('span').text
        title = soup.find('h3').find('span').text
        content = soup.find('p', class_ = 'mb-0_2CX').text
        rating = soup.find('div', class_ = 'mb-4_2RH align-items-center_3Oi flex-wrap_ATH d-flex_oSG')
        rating = rating.find('div')['title']
        final_list.append([name, location, policy, rating,  title, content])
    except AttributeError:
        pass
reviews = pd.DataFrame(final_list, columns = ['Name', 'Location', 'Policy', 'Rating', 'Title', 'Content'])
print(reviews)
```

But when I edit

```
for div in soup.find('div', class_ = 'loadingOverlay_24D'):
```

to

```
for div in soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'loadingOverlay_24D'):
```

I don't get all reviews, I just get the same entry looped over and over.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The CSS classes you use to identify reviews are incorrect. For example, `loadingOverlay_24D` is not the reviews containing `div`

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue 1: Repeated data inside the loop

You loop has the following form:

```
for div in soup.find('div' , ...):
    name = soup.find('h4', ... )
    policy = soup.find('div', ... )
    ...
```

Notice that you are calling `find` inside the loop for the `soup` object. This means that each time you try to find the value for `name`,  it will search the whole document from the beginning and return the first match, in every iteration.

This is why you are getting the same data over and over.

To fix this, you need to call `find` inside the current review `div` that you are currently  at. That is:

```
 for div in soup.find('div' , ...):
    name = div.find('h4', ... )
    policy = div.find('div', ... )
    ...
```

#### Issue 2: Missing data and error handling

In your code, any errors inside the loop are ignored. However, there are many errors that are actually happening while parsing and extracting the values. For example:

```
    location = div.find('h4').find('small').text
```

Not all reviews have location information. Hence, the code will extract `h4`, then try to find `small`, but won't find any, returning `None`. Then you are calling `.text` on that `None` object, causing an exception. Hence, this review will not be added to the result data frame.

To fix this, you need to add more error checking. For example:

```
  locationDiv = div.find('h4').find('small')
  if locationDiv:
      location = locationDiv.text
  else:
      location = ''
```

#### Issue 3: Identifying and extracting data

The page you're trying to parse has broken HTML, and uses CSS classes that seem random or at least inconsistent. You need to find the correct and unique identifiers for the data that you are extracting such that they strictly match all the entries.

For example, you are extracting the review-container `div` using CSS class `loadingOverlay_24D`. This is incorrect. This CSS class seems to be for a "loading" placeholder div or something similar. Actual reviews are enclosed in  `div` blocks that look like this:

```
<div itemscope="" itemType="http://schema.org/Review" itemProp="review">
.... 
</div>
```

Notice that the uniquely identifying property is the `itemProp` attribute. You can extract those `div` blocks using:

```
soup.find('div', {'itemprop': 'review'}):
```

Similarly, you have to find the correct identifying properties of the other data you want to extract to ensure you get all your data fully and correctly.

One more thing, when a tag has more than one CSS class, usually only one of them is the identifying property you want to use. For example, for names, you have this:

```
name = soup.find('h4', class_ = 'my-0_27D align-items-baseline_kxl flex-row_3gP d-inline-flex_1j8 text-muted_2v5')
```

but in reality, you don't need all these classes. The first class, in this case, is sufficient to identify the name `h4` blocks

```
name = soup.find('h4', class_ = 'my-0_27D')
```

#### Example:

Here's an example to extract the author names from review page:

```
 for div in soup.find_all('div', {'itemprop': 'review'}):
    name = div.find('h4', class_ = 'my-0_27D')
    if (name): 
        name = name.find('span').text
    else:
        name = '-'
    print(name)
```

Output:

```
Aidan
Bruno M.
Ba. I.
Luca Evangelista
Upset
Julian L.
Alison Peck
...
```

Comment: Thanks so much Aziz, thorough explanation. I am working through your solution now.

Answer (score -2):

The page servs broken html code and html.parser is better at dealing with it.

Change `soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')` to `soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')`

Comment: The page is definitely broken, but this doesn't change the result at all.